# Coalesce values in one column based on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

How do I coalesce values in a column grouped by another column?

e.g. How do I coalesce column 2 values by column 1 values? So turn the following:

```
Column 1|Column 2
-----------------
A       |Bob
A       |
B       |Mary
C       |
C       |Kevin
C       |
D       |
D       |
```

Into this:

```
Column 1|Column 2
-----------------
A       |Bob
B       |Mary
C       |Kevin
D       |
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a `Column 1` with two different names in `Column 2` what's the tie-breaker -- or, does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation.  Here is one way:

```
select col1, max(col2)
from t
group by col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  col1, 
  unnest(
    coalesce(
      (array_agg(distinct col2) filter (where col2 is not null)),
      '{null}'
    )
  ) 
from t 
group by col1;
```

More complex but also works with data like

```
Column 1|Column 2
-----------------
A       |Bob
A       |Marley
B       |Mary
C       |
C       |Kevin
C       |Costner
D       |
D       |
```